# If statement executing even when false

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, recursion

So I have an if statement that checks the id of the draggable that was just dropped in the droppable. I have checked in the console using `console.log` to see if the the if statement is working properly. It is returning the right true/false value but even if it returns false it still executes the code and not the else. I haven't posted to much code because I am quite sure that it is a problem with my if statement and not with the code as a whole. The if statement executes regardless of what I put after the ===. I saw someone else had this problem and it was something to do with infinite recursion, but the answer was too specific to his code for me to understand.

```
$("#game1drop1").droppable ({
    drop: function(e,ui) {
        if ($(ui.draggable[0].id === "game1img1")) {
            $("#game1drop1").addClass("correct")}
        }
        else{
            $(ui.draggable[0]).addClass("positionWrong")
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: this expression is strange `$(ui.draggable[0].id === "game1img1")`, the whole boolean expression is put into `$(...)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you have `$()` wrapped around your test. So it's equivalent to:

```
if ($(false)) {
```

This is wrapping `false` in a jQuery object, and all objects are truthy.

It should be:

```
if (ui.draggable[0].id === "game1img1") {
```